# when exporting my data into csv, my output is in disorder maybe because of tabs and whitespaces

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
class Job(Item):
    a_title = Field()
    b_url = Field()
    c_date = Field()
    d_pub = Field()

 class stage(Spider):
    name = 'jobs'
    start_urls = ['http://www.stagiaire.com/offres-stages.html/']

    def parse(self, response):

        for i in response.css('.info-offre'):

            title = i.css('.titleads::text').extract()
            url = i.css('.titleads::attr(href)').extract()
            date = i.css('.date-offre.tip::text').extract()
            pub = i.css('.content-1+ .content-1 .date-offre::text').extract()

            yield Job(a_title=title, b_url=url, c_date=date, d_pub=pub)
```

[this my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZZmt.jpg)

Comment: Wrap all code in tags

Comment: Could you post csv text source rather than an image?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using scrapy ItemLoader's you put concrete lists to your results where you are probably expecting single elements. To fix this use `extract_first()` instead of `extract()` to get only the first xpath selection.

In your case it should be:

```
title = i.css('.titleads::text').extract_first('')  # defaults to ''
url = i.css('.titleads::attr(href)').extract_first('').strip()  # get rid of spaces and /n etc.
date = i.css('.date-offre.tip::text').extract_first('')
pub = i.css('.content-1+ .content-1 .date-offre::text').extract_first('')
```

Actually seems like you want to use an [ItemLoader](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) here to clean all fields of newlines etc.

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader.processors import Compose, TakeFirst

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = Field()

class MyItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MyItem
    # this will process every field in the item, take first element and remove all newlines and trailing spaces
    default_output_processor = Compose(TakeFirst(), 
                                       lambda v: v.replace('\n','').strip())  # get rid of new lines
```

This might look like a lot but Item Loaders are just wrappers around item objects which do something when you either put a value in it or take it out. In the example above it will process all values, take first element if it's a list and remove any newlines.

Then when just create the loader and load in some fields!

```
loader = MyItemLoader(selector=response)
loader.add_css('title', '.titleads::text')
loader.add_css('url', '.titleads::attr(href)')
loader.add_css('date', '.date-offre.tip::text')
loader.add_css('pub', '.content-1+ .content-1 .date-offre::text')
return loader.load_item()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems that it's not working for my code. it gives an exceptions.AttributeError : 'Selectorlist' has no attribute 'extract_first'. am i missing something! importing a method maybe? to your knawledge when i extract the first two items(title-url) there is no problem but when i add the last two items(date-pub) to my code it gives a file not orginized! another info that can help, when i create a dataframe using pandas i realise that there is alot of metacharacters \n\t\t\t   in both (date and pub) . thank you in advance

Comment: @K.ossama `extract_first()` was only added in scrapy v1.1 so you probably just need to update your scrapy. To get rid of the backslash characters you can `strip()` the results (see my edit). If you have any other issues you should provided your results in text format rather than a screenshot, then we can see what's wrong exactly.

Comment: thanks @Granitosaurus i have updated my scrapy but still giving the same problem : you can find here my output and thanks again: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah5DCQ19IxysgQLtVn7JhWHDpuaT

Comment: @K.ossama To me your csv looks fine other than bunch of newlines in `pub` field. To get rid of the newlines you can take a look at my edit. Csv is a comma seperated value format, scrapy automatically quotes every value in double quotes, maybe the program you are using to view the csv expects some different quote character? i.e. this is what scrapy gives: `"field1","field2","field3"`.

Comment: Thanks again @Granitosaurus! i find your edit very useful in this point